# Problem with linear mass density of which varies according to the law $μ = kx + a$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

I have some problem solving this exercise:
A wire of length $L = 10$ m has a linear mass density of which varies according to the law $$μ = kx + a$$ with $k = 1.8$ g m-2, $a = 0.5$ g m-1. The wire is subjected to a force τ = 4 N.$$$$
Calculate the time taken to travel the entire wire from a pulse generated at one end.$$$$I know that
$$v=\sqrt{\frac Tμ}$$
so 
$$v=\sqrt{\frac T{kx + a}}$$
$$d\xi=\sqrt{\frac T{kx + a}}dt$$
And integrating with respect to time
$$\xi(x,t)=\sqrt{\frac T{kx + a}}t$$
I supposed that i need to impose 
$$x=L $$ $$\xi(x,t)=L$$ However I know that this execution is wrong maybe from the integration..
Someone can help me?
Thank you a lot for your time and your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to consider displacement. The time to travel a path is:

$ t = \int_0^L{\frac{dx}{v(x)}} $

so substitute in your expression for the position dependent velocity (in terms of the tension and the linear mass density) and do the integral.